# Obscure Vim feature: +footer?

Tags: gvim, options

Inspecting some of Vim's features listed by `vim --version` I have noticed some obscure ones, for example, `balloon_eval`, `balloon_eval_term` and `footer`.

There is an example in the documentation to test the balloons (if curious, see [`:h balloon_show`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html)), but almost nothing is said about the footer, only that it is also related to debuggers and that it can be enabled with `:set guioptions+=F`.

The command displays a footer at the bottom of the window, but I am clueless about how to interact with it. The search engine has also failed me, it seems some people use the term to designate the statusbar... **Can anyone share a minimal example that involves the footer?** This is out of sheer curiosity, but maybe this will be useful for debuggers developers too.

Note: I did compile Vim with Motif for my tests. The footer does show up after `:se go+=F` and `:echo has("footer")` returns 1. But I don't know how to interact with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Footer" is a predefined widget's class from Motif library. The only machine I ever saw this stuff live was an old UltraSparc workstation running Sun Solaris 9 (CDE) circa 10 years ago. Never tried to code anything for it though.

It looks like "Footer" in Motif is nothing more than "StatusBar" for other platforms. GVim "Motif"-build uses it to display "status bar messages" instead of "balloon hints" under the tool bar as in Windows or GTK builds. So nothing really fancy.